# I am attempting to use pandas to turn a long dataset into a wide dataset, but I want to keep repeated index values on separate rows

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I am starting with a dataset that looks like: (updated: added Qstn Resp TS to help match up Resp Value to Qstn Title.

```
longDF = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                        'Qstn Title':['Date Services were P','Date of Request','Services Requested','Type of Oral Service','Date Services were P','Date of Request','Describe how to resolve','Services Requested','Type of Oral Service','Date Services were P','Date Services were P','Date Services were P','Date Services were P','Date of Request','Date of Request','Describe how to resolve','Services Requested','Services Requested','Services Requested','Type of Oral Service','Type of Oral Service','Type of Oral Service'],
                        'Resp Value':['05/01/2020','05/01/2020','Chinese (Cantonese)','Telephone Interpreter','07/31/2020','07/31/2020','services were provided','Chinese (Cantonese)','Telephone Interpreter','09/24/2020','09/24/2020','11/19/2020','09/24/2020','09/24/2020','11/19/2020','interpreter lm on vm','Vietnamese','Vietnamese','Vietnamese','Telephone Interpreter','Telephone Interpreter','Telephone Interpreter'],
                        'Qstn Resp TS':['5/1/2020','5/1/2020','5/1/2020','5/1/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','9/24/2020','9/24/2020','11/19/2020','9/24/2020','9/24/2020','11/19/2020','11/19/2020','9/24/2020','9/24/2020','11/19/2020','9/24/2020','9/24/2020','11/19/2020']})
```

To create the wide dataset I do:

```
wideDF = pd.pivot_table(longDF, values='Resp Value',  index=['id'], columns='Qstn Title', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

My goal is to produce a single row for each 'ID' and 'Qstn Title' set where column name='Qstn Title' and values='Resp Value', so wideDF should have 6 rows.  When I attempt using pivot_table command above I only get 3 rows. The 'Qstn Title' columns will have multiple 'Resp Values' for 'ID' 3 because of the aggfunc=np.sum.

Expected output:

```
wideDFout = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,3,3,3],
                          'Date Services were P':['05/01/2020','07/31/2020','09/24/2020','09/24/2020','09/24/2020','11/19/2020'],
                          'Date of Request':['05/01/2020','07/31/2020','09/24/2020','','','11/19/2020'],
                          'Services Requested':['Chinese (Cantonese)','Chinese (Cantonese)','Vietnamese','Vietnamese','','Vietnamese'],
                          'Type of Oral Service':['Telephone Interpreter','Chinese (Cantonese)','Telephone Interpreter','Telephone Interpreter','','Telephone Interpreter'],
                          'Describe how to resolve':['','services were provided','','interpreter lm on vm','','']})
```

Is there a way to go from long to wide while preserving the index/rows for a set of column values?

Below is corrected input dataframe and script to produce desired output:

```
longDF2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                        'Qstn Title':['Date Services were P','Date of Request','Services Requested','Type of Oral Service','Date Services were P','Date of Request','Describe how to resolve','Services Requested','Type of Oral Service','Date Services were P','Date Services were P','Date Services were P','Date of Request','Date of Request','Date of Request','Describe how to resolve','Services Requested','Services Requested','Services Requested','Type of Oral Service','Type of Oral Service','Type of Oral Service'],
                        'Resp Value':['05/01/2020','05/01/2020','Chinese (Cantonese)','Telephone Interpreter','07/31/2020','07/31/2020','services were provided','Chinese (Cantonese)','Telephone Interpreter','09/24/2020','09/24/2020','11/19/2020','09/24/2020','09/24/2020','11/19/2020','interpreter lm on vm','Vietnamese','Vietnamese','Vietnamese','Telephone Interpreter','Telephone Interpreter','Telephone Interpreter'],
                        'Qstn Resp TS':['5/1/2020','5/1/2020','5/1/2020','5/1/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','7/31/2020','9/24/2020','9/24/2020','11/19/2020','9/24/2020','9/24/2020','11/19/2020','11/19/2020','9/24/2020','9/24/2020','11/19/2020','9/24/2020','9/24/2020','11/19/2020']})

# add temp column 'q' to hold sub-id for each repeated id
longDF2['q'] = longDF2.groupby(['id','Qstn Title','Qstn Resp TS'], group_keys = False).cumcount()

# create multiIndex dataframe based on id, sub-id and qestion title
# and then unstack it
longDFOut2 = longDF2.set_index(['id','q','Qstn Title','Qstn Resp TS']).unstack(level=2, fill_value='')


#### re-pivot ##########
longDFOutNew2 = pd.DataFrame(longDFOut2.to_records())

# rename columns        
for c in range(len(longDFOutNew2.columns)):
    #print('index='+str(c)+' - name='+longDFOutNew2.columns[c])
    if c > 2:
        longDFOutNew2.rename(columns={longDFOutNew2.columns[c]:longDFOutNew2.columns[c].split(',')[1].strip()[1:-2]}, inplace=True)

# pad ID with zeros
longDFOutNew2['id'] = longDFOutNew2['id'].astype(str).str.zfill(10)

# output cleaned dataframe
longDFOutFinal2 = longDFOutNew2[['id','Date Services were P','Date of Request','Describe how to resolve','Services Requested','Type of Oral Service']]
```

Comment: Will you please provide a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we create a helper column 'q' that increments for each repeated 'Qstn Title' within each id. It will serve as a sub-id, essentially, for those id groups with repeated 'Qstn Title's:

```
longDF['q'] = longDF.groupby(['id','Qstn Title'], group_keys = False).cumcount()
```

Now we have groups defined by 'id' and 'q', and we can use that to `unstack`:

```
longDF.set_index(['id','q','Qstn Title']).unstack()
```

output

```
Resp Value
Qstn Title  Date Services were P    Date of Request Describe how to resolve Services Requested  Type of Oral Service
id  q                   
1   0       05/01/2020              05/01/2020      NaN                  Chinese (Cantonese)    Telephone Interpreter
2   0       07/31/2020              07/31/2020      services were provided  Chinese (Cantonese) Telephone Interpreter
3   0       09/24/2020              09/24/2020      interpreter lm on vm    Vietnamese  Telephone Interpreter
    1       09/24/2020              11/19/2020      NaN               Vietnamese    Telephone Interpreter
    2       11/19/2020              NaN             NaN               Vietnamese    Telephone Interpreter
    3       09/24/2020              NaN             NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: This is very close to what the expected output is.  On the initial post I did not provide a field that could be used to ensure values are from same date as response.  I added the Qstn Resp TS field to compare with Date Services were P.

Comment: @Brandon so what is missing/wrong?

Comment: For id=1 in column 'q' - the Date of Request is 11/19/202 but the Date of Service was 11/19/2020.  I added the wideDFout to show what the expected output is.  I updated the longDF to include Qstn Resp TS to use as a way to match values to Date Services were P.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but, I have a few updates.  First, I realized after this great submission from @piterbarg that something else must be wrong.  My original/updated dataframe longDF had a wrong value in the Qstn Title column.  This threw off the groupby, set_index & unstack operations.  

Second, in order to get all values in the correct row I needed to change the groupby, set_index and unstack to this by adding 'Qstn Resp TS': 

longDFOut2 = longDF2.set_index(['id','q','Qstn Title','Qstn Resp TS']).unstack(level=2, fill_value='')